# Check the result of a math expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, functions, where, exec

Let's say I have a table, which has four columns (`a`, `b`, `oper` and `c`) and some primary key column. `oper` means *arithmetic operation* (`+ - * /`) here.

```
a  b  oper  c
-------------
2  3  +     5
4  2  /     3
6  1  *     9
8  5  -     3
```

As, we can see in some cases, `a <oper> b != c`. So, my question is how to filter out such cases?

I've heard of `execute`, which is used for executing statements, but I don't know how to use it inside `where` clause.

Also, I'm not generalizing the `oper` to *any* arithmetic operation, but it would be nice to know, if any function exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because SQL differentiates code and data reasonably well in the syntax function like the following is required:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(a int, op char(1), b int)
   RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC RETURN
CASE op
WHEN '+' THEN a + b
WHEN '*' THEN a * b
WHEN '/' THEN a / b
WHEN '-' THEN a - b
END
```

once you have that you can use a query:

```
select a, op, b, c
from maths
where test(a,op,b) = c
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=77b76cdbce4efc6e6a20c32f30fbd37c)